# Method to find the statistically significant clickthrough rate of several groups with no control

Tags: statistical-significance

I have basic data that looks like this:

```
Group    Visits   Clicks
A        2029     186
B        2340     171
C        2780     176
```

And I'm trying to determine whether one of the clickthrough rates (`Clicks / Visits`) is statistically better than the rest of the clicks. I have tried using a Chi Squared test to determine that these groups are in fact different, but am then stuck as to how to determine the 'best'. By eyeballing the numbers I can see that A is the best clickthrough, but is there  a test that would show this absolutely?

Comment: Are the Clicks also in the Visits (i.e. Clicks / Visits can never be greater than 1)?

Comment: Correct @John, when I do the Chi Square test it's actually 'clicked' or 'didn't click' where `'didn't click' = visits - clicked'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I'm assuming you had a significant $\chi^2$ test, which is not explicit in your question)*

Why do anything other than interpret your data in light of your model? Could `B` or `C` possibly be best, based on your data?

You could just test for subsets. Do a $\chi^2$ containing just `A` and `B`, and then do one just containing `B` and `C`. What if they're not significant? Then what would you conclude? What if you get significant effects but they go away when you correct for alpha inflation? Then what do you conclude? What if you find `A` is not different from `B` but `B` is different from `C`? Would you really want to say `A` and `B` are equal? There are myriad questions, many of them problematic, that can stem from further testing when you've already asked a question and received a perfectly adequate answer.

Your question is that click versus not click depends on group. You did a test of that. Interpret the results you have to mean something because, according to your test, they likely do. I'd just say:

"I tested whether clicks depend on group,  $\chi^2$ = xxx, *p* = xxx. The best rate was A with 9.2%, followed by B with 7.3% and C with 6.3%."

If you want to do something more interesting and potentially useful, don't just report tests but report estimates and confidence intervals. You can generate confidence intervals around your probabilities of click. You could look this up on the [internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Confidence_intervals) or use the binom package in R, which can perform any of the methods (or just use the one given in binom.test, which is conservative).

Comment: You've cut to the quick of my statistical inadequacies @John, and quickly too! I appreciate you taking the time. The $\chi^2$ value was significant (don't have the data in front of me, but significant at the 99% for sure). To clarify what you're suggesting, the results would be something like "Clicks depend on groups at the 99% interval ($\chi^2 = x, p = y$)" then use a binomial proportion confidence interval to state the expected range of each rate?

Comment: More or less, I'd not say "at the 99% interval". I'd just report the p-value. And personally I'd not even use the word significant. I'd just say they had an effect and report the test result. Then describe the data. The description should have a measure of variability and CI's would be best.